# Facebook Open Graph protocol not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

Ok, i know there's a lot of posts on this topic and i have read through a lot of them; however, i have yet to be able to solve my problem.

I am trying to add a Facebook like button to a website and use the Open Graph protocol to send specific information for the post that gets posted to the persons news feed that clicks the like button.

This is the code blocks i am using on the site:

HTML tag:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://developers.facebook.com/schema/">
```

Meta Tags:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="ethneCITY - Reaching the unreached in the urban center!" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.ethnecity.com/dev/images/share.png" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="ethneCITY" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="61800397" />
<meta property="og:description" content="100 yrs ago we sent missionaries to the nations to look for the cities. Today you go to the cities & you find the nations." />
```

Like button code generated from Facebook's like button creation tool:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=145713945515336&amp;xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="http://www.ethnecity.com" send="true" layout="button_count" width="150" show_faces="false" action="like" colorscheme="dark" font="tahoma"></fb:like>
```

How it appears on my news feed right now? (not what i want) - http://tinypic.com/r/axi2kg/7

Anyone have any ideas why when i click the like button it only displays the post on my news feed like this instead of using the meta tags for the feed content?

Answer (score 2):

Did you lint it?

Its data is likely out of date/cached and it just hasn't updated yet.

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug