# How do i change thumbnail image in a fb comment post?

Tags: php, facebook, image, facebook-graph-api

When I post a comment through a webpage I created, Facebook tries to retrieve some images from that particular page and chooses a thumbnail to the the post as it wants. How can I choose the image of this thumbnail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [use facebook open graph meta tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/keyconcepts/).

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://davidwalsh.name/wp-content/themes/klass/img/facebooklogo.png"/>
```

Don't forget that you need to have your html tag looks like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://developers.facebook.com/schema/">
```

Also here is (at [davidwalsh.name](http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags)) a nice article about this topic

And as written in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7183138/461989): the data could be cached by facebbok, you could check it by the special facebook debug tool here: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: thanks at last the og: image affected the post . BUT :            when i put:

  <meta property="og:image"   content="<?=$config['SITE_URL'].'Images/Items/Thumbnails/thumb_Item24.jpg'?>" />

the object debugger accepts and finds the image , but when i put it like this:

<meta property="og:image"   content="<?=$config['SITE_URL'].'Images/Items/Thumbnails/thumb_'.$itemImage?>"/> 

where $itemImage is Item24.jpg , object debugger doesn't recognize it and chooses another one. why ? anything wrong with the concatination ??

Answer (score 0):

Add an og:image meta tag to the page. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/reference/ for more information